# How to change 2D array elements in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to iterate the source array in order to change a few elements in the destination array, but I can’t get the correct indexes, I have incomprehensible offsets. In general, my task is to change the element if the conditions require it

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1000, 1000/50)
y = np.linspace(0,1000, 1000/50)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

source =  np.column_stack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).astype(int)
destination = source.copy()

for x, i in np.ndenumerate(source):
    # if smth:
    destination[i] = np.array([x[0] + 10, x[1]])
```

I think I should not use the source array, but only iterate over the destination array(сannot be done using standard methods), tell me the correct solution, thanks in advance.

```
Current output:
[421 789]
[473 789]
[526 789]
[578 789]
[631 789]
[684 789]


Required output:
[431 789]
[483 789]
[536 789]
[588 789]
[641 789]
[694 789]
```

I’ll explain more simply, I have a grid, it has points, I need to shift the points, say 88, 89, 90, 10 pixels to the right, for this I need to have an array of source and destination (where these points are offset), enumerate most likely it doesn’t suit me, but the usual editing of an array like for x in destination: when editing x gives the desired result, but this does not apply to ndarray

[image]

```
for x, i in enumerate(destination):
     inside = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (destination[x,0], 
     destination[x,1]), False)
   if inside > 0:
    cv2.circle(img, (destination[x,0], destination[x,1]), 10, 
  (255,0,0), 2)
    destination[x] = np.array([destination[x,0] + 10, destination[x,1]])

 # Contour(cnt)
 [[550  42]
 [600  42]
 [690 273]
 [640 273]]
```

As you understand, I need to shift everything that is circled in blue by 10 pixels

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: `if smth:` sounds like a task for `np.where`

Comment: @QuangHoang, This is a condition with OpenCV, I did not insert it here, maybe someone may not have it

Comment: how do you get these `desired` values? what is the mathematical equation behind?

Comment: @makis I use cv2.pointPolygonTest to check if these points are in the given area, if so then I shift them 10 pixels to the right

Comment: you want to shift only the one coordinate (only one column?)

Comment: @makis Lets imagine that for x and y, I need to add 10 pixels

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

From data creation to target-region modification, we can divide it into a three step process. The modification can be achieved using `numpy` indexing along with conditional region selection by means of `numpy.where` and `numpy.logical_and` (if necessary).

#### 1. Make Data

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1000, int(1000/50))
y = np.linspace(0,1000, int(1000/50))
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

source =  np.column_stack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).astype(int)
destination = source.copy()
```

#### 2. Use Conditional Statement to Find Target Region

```py
target_index = np.where(np.logical_and(destination[:,1]==789, destination[:,0]>=421))
destination[target_index]
```

**Output**:

```
array([[ 421,  789],
       [ 473,  789],
       [ 526,  789],
       [ 578,  789],
       [ 631,  789],
       [ 684,  789],
       [ 736,  789],
       [ 789,  789],
       [ 842,  789],
       [ 894,  789],
       [ 947,  789],
       [1000,  789]])
```

> #### 3. Make changes to the target region

```py
scope = destination[target_index] 
scope[:,0] = scope[:,0] + 10
destination[target_index] = scope
destination[target_index]
```

**Output**:

```
array([[ 431,  789],
       [ 483,  789],
       [ 536,  789],
       [ 588,  789],
       [ 641,  789],
       [ 694,  789],
       [ 746,  789],
       [ 799,  789],
       [ 852,  789],
       [ 904,  789],
       [ 957,  789],
       [1010,  789]])
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution is very close, but I need to change the points in a certain shape. I don't know how to use np where for this. I will update the description, thanks in advance.

Comment: @question_mark_77 I took a look at the image and edited it to focus on the example you have shown. What I understand is that you have an objective that can be broken down into multiple smaller objectives. This answer served the purpose of explaining the question you asked. However, the problem you are posing now, is a different problem: you need to find out your business logic to determine those points and their offsets. Please create a separate Stackoverflow question with a tag to `imageprocessing`. Leave a reference to this question there. Please mark an answers as the **`accepted`** one.

Comment: Not a problem, just one theoretical question, can I use np.where for these purposes?

Comment: Theoretically speaking, yes. `np.where` basically means **where(some condition)**. So, as long as you have your _condition_ defined properly and that evaluates to an array of Boolean values, you should be able to use `np.where`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not clear at all. How to do you want to modify the `destination`?

Also, are you sure you need `np.ndenumerate` and not `enumerate` ?

Here is a way to modify it based on the values that are in `sources`.
At the position (index) `x`, the destination will become equal to the `x` element of the first column of `source`+ 10 and equal to the `x` element of the second column of `source`.

```
for index, value in enumerate(source):
    destination[index] = [source[index,0]+10, source[index,1]] # x+10, y same
```